# Where to buy a one-way travel insurance from the UK to the USA

Tags: usa, insurance

I am moving to the USA next year to take up employment. I will arrive two weeks before I begin my work. I need health coverage for the two weeks between arrival and my employee health benefits begin. I would also like to have typical travel insurance benefits for my outbound trip. It seems there is a product called 'One way travel insurance' which gives me exactly what I need, but only a company called 'Go Walkabout Travel Insurance' provides it. Is this something I can request from other companies, ideally ones I might have heard of? My family and I are all UK resident, registered with UK GPs and have no pre-existing health conditions.

Update: The problem here is that standard travel insurance policies do not cover travelers who are not planning to return. I can't point to a online source for this but, for example, I called *Insure* and *Go* to confirm this and was told that a standard policy would expire 24 hours after passing US customs if I did not intend to return to the UK.

Where can I find an insurance for my need?

Comment: No - It seems to be administratively difficult to arrange standard coverage in the USA without a social security number.    I won't even know my address in the States until a week before I travel, which is a further difficulty.

Comment: No.  I'd rather it was provided from the UK.

Comment: Okay, I just understood your original question.   My understanding is that standard travel insurance does not cover travelers who are not intending to return.

Comment: Rather than travel insurance, you might look at [short-term health insurance](https://www.ehealthinsurance.com/short-term-health-insurance), in the US, for what you describe, those few weeks before the employer-provided plans kick in. Check with your employer, though; some plans are not in place on day 1. I have no knowledge of the linked site, but offer it as an example.

Comment: And, without the social security number, you can get [visitors insurance](http://www.visitorscoverage.com/) which acts like a short-term plan, and acknowledges that new arrivals may not yet have the number. Again, this is an example.

Comment: Just take the risk and live without insurance for a couple of weeks. As far as I know the US government doesn't check if you have one.